# How to display duplicated results only in MYSQLI?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display only the duplicated results in a PHP page, not their count and there is a condition where certain field can't be empty. What is the mysqli query for displaying each duplicated result and not grouping them so it displays all the duplicates in 1 row rather than displaying each duplicate in a single row?

This is for a reporting panel on full PHP website. I have tried some queries like `SELECT col1,col2 FROM table Where col3!='' GROUP BY col2 HAVING COUNT(col1) > 1;` But this will display the duplicated results in 1 row, if I have 3 duplicates with same col2 the query returns only one due to the `GROUP BY col2` clause, I tried `GROUP BY col2,col1` but now `HAVING COUNT(col1) > 1` can never be true since it is impossible to have same value of `col1`.

I expect the output of the query to display each duplicated result in a row and not group them in 1 row only. In other words to display the same 3 duplicated results having same col2 but different other columns values and not display only their 1 result.

All results:
[image]

Query I tried:
[image]

Comment: Please, add some examples. What you have in input and what you expect at output?

Comment: Sure I'll add some images now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`SELECT * FROM usersl Where hash!='' AND user_fullName IN (SELECT user_fullName FROM usersl HAVING COUNT(user_fullName) > 1);`

This will give you result as you want

Comment: The query is pretty logical and I have tried before but didn't fetch the desired results. https://prnt.sc/ok944g

Comment: this query will fetch only those users whose fullName column has duplicate entries. If not fetching then 
use `GROUP BY user_fullName` in inner Query

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add one more column in group by clause and that column should be Primary ID column then you will got your desired result.

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM table Where col3!='' GROUP BY col2,pk_id;
```

Comment: PK is unique, how adding it to GROUP BY would help to get all fields that were grouped by `col2`?

Comment: @Justinas kindly describe you question, I have added pk_id along with col2 because, data will grouped (col2) with no repetition but when we add another unique column so it will return all repeated results.

Comment: The issue here is that you are counting the empty col3 duplicates and displaying the only the result with col3. Duplicates only counts when both results have col3. here are some screen shots .https://prnt.sc/ok986w  https://prnt.sc/ok98bv

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this helps you.

```
SELECT u1.* FROM usersl AS u1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_fullName FROM usersl WHERE hash != '' GROUP BY (user_fullName) HAVING COUNT(user_fullName) > 1) AS u2 ON u1.user_fullName = u2.user_fullName 
WHERE u1.hash!=''
```

Answer (score -1):

First find all ID's of these fields:

```
$ids = $db->queryColumn(
    "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') FROM table WHERE col3 != '' GROUP BY col2 HAVING COUNT(col1) > 1"
);
```

Then make array of ID's:

```
$idsToFind = [];

foreach ($ids as $idString) {
    array_push($idsToFind, array_walk('trim', explode(',', $idString)));
}
```

Now do another query where you find elements by ID:

```
$db->queryAll(
    'SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE id IN :idArray',
    $this->escapeArray($idsToFind)
);
```